# How to retain cursor position when using :%!filtercmd in vim?

Tags: vim

When I issue a vim command that starts with `:%!`, such as `:%!sort` to sort all lines in the buffer, the cursor moves to the first line. How do I preserve the cursor position?

Ultimately, I want to use this command in an `autocmd`, such as:

```
augroup filetype_xxx
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWrite *.xxx :%!sort
augroup END
```

Will the same method work in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use the **Preserve** function. Beyond solving your problem in this particular task you can use it for much more.

```
" preserve function
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
             "silent! keepjumps keeppatterns execute a:command
            silent! execute 'keeppatterns keepjumps ' . a:command
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfunction
endif

augroup filetype_xxx
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWrite *.xxx :call Preserve("%!sort")
augroup END
```

You can also use the "Preserve Function" to perform other useful tasks like:

```
command! -nargs=0 Reindent :call Preserve('exec "normal! gg=G"')
```

```
DelBlankLines')
    fun! DelBlankLines() range
        if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
            call Preserve(':%s/\s\+$//e')
            call Preserve(':%s/^\n\{2,}/\r/ge')
        endif
    endfun
endif
command! -nargs=0 DelBlank :call DelBlankLines()
nnoremap <Leader>d :call DelBlankLines()<cr>

" remove trailing spaces
if !exists('*StripTrailingWhitespace')
    function! StripTrailingWhitespace()
        if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
            call Preserve(":%s,\\s\\+$,,e")
        endif
    endfunction
endif
command! Cls call StripTrailingWhitespace()
cnoreabbrev cls Cls
cnoreabbrev StripTrailingSpace Cls
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mark to remember the current line number (but note that the line contents could change):

```
augroup filetype_xxx
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWrite *.xxx :kk
    autocmd BufWrite *.xxx :%!sort
    autocmd BufWrite *.xxx :'k
augroup END
```